# When Customer Register from checkout page then which Magento event called?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, event-observer

Customer can add the product in cart and without logged in he is click on proceed to checkout page.

From there is is create the account then which event called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you use the Onepage checkout process, you can try this event which is triggered when the customer model is instantiated during the creation of the quote `core_copy_fieldset_customer_account_to_quote`

The event data are:

- target: Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
- source: Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
- root: string 'global'

Hope it helps. Otherwise you can take a look at the class and method `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::_validateCustomerData`

Comment: You're welcome. Vote if it helped :-)

Comment: actually I have no points when I got then I will vote for you (y)

Answer (score 3):

use `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after` event to get customer before `customer_login`
or use `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` if you want `customer_login` event trigger first

then in your observer method:

```
public function onServiceQuoteSubmitAfter($observer) {

    /** @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    if ($quote->getData('checkout_method') != Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER) {
        return;
    }

    $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
    //manipulate $customer
}
```

Pay attention that `$quote->getData()` is used instead of magic `Varien_Object` getter.
Hope it helps someone

Comment: This is actually the more suitable answer because `core_copy_fieldset_customer_account_to_quote` gets triggered before the registration is complete and it still can be aborted.